# Wordpress 4.1 support Markdown syntax or I've to install a Plugin?

Tags: markdown

I read at:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown/

Wordpress supports Markdown. But i not find at wy wordpress 4.1 the option to active Wordpress. Maybe the docs are obsolete?

Moreover I find a lot of Markdown related plugins for Wordpress and that makes me thing Markdown support is not available in wordpress by default.

Maybe someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: That, my friend, is documentation for WordPress.com. [There's a difference](https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/). They have installed a plugin to support Markdown, as should you.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh now I understand Wordpress.com docs are not the same as wordpress docs! I think sometimes is a little confusing. I've installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-markdown/ and woala Markdown support. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

wordpress do not support markdown, you need a plugin for that. Although there are many similarities, in general wordpress.com != wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try [WordPress Markdown plugin](https://terryl.in/en/repository/wordpress-markdown-plugin-githuber-md/)。

Git: https://github.com/terrylinooo/githuber-md

Plugin page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-githuber-md/

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I've found for Markdown everywhere in WordPress 4.9 to 5.8 (as of 7/2021) is [Parsedown for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/parsedown-wp/). I've [answered why in more depth here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/391507/90938).